# Is it possible to increase the size of the text for received messages in Lotus Sametime?

Tags: fonts, lotus-notes, accessibility, lotus-sametime

I'm using Sametime 8.5.1 on Windows 7 and I would like the text to appear bigger.

I tried changing the settings in `File > Preferences > Sametime > Chat Window > Chat Font`, but this changes my font, not the senders font.

Is it possible to increase the size of the text for received messages in Lotus Sametime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you go to **Preferences** > **Sametime** > **Chat Window** > Under **Display Settings** select "Always use my font settings and ignore any styles sent by others". Let us know how you go!! :)

Comment: That does work...though I find it a little bit hacky.

Comment: OK. I'm no Lotus Notes guru that's for sure but that's what I do. Sorry couldn't be more helpful. The other option is to ask people who you correspond with regularly to change their settings and increase their font size. I just did it with one of my co-workers. Most people don't even realise so would probably be happy for the knowledge. :)

Comment: I like to see the fonts of the people I correspond with.  Gives me a good idea of what kind of person they are :P  I've got a Surface Pro 3 (which has a crazy high native resolution).  Windows DPI settings help with most applications but Notes seems to do its own thing.  Most of the interface is readable, except for received messages as per OP.